# PHP die() command error checking

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem with the die() commands.  I have a member registration page on my website, with a form whose action is another php script. Once submitted, instead of an alert with the correct error, the page gets redirected to my temp_handle.php with the error command echoed. Also, the success method does not redirect the page. I am building a new version of the previous page and I have co-opted the previous author's code so I know this method works somewhat. I am restyling it with bootstrap.

```
...
<form class="form-horizontal" action="2/temp_handle.php" id="registerForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
</form>
...
```

This form is submitted to temp_handle.php which executes:

```
$first_name = sanitize($_POST['first_name']);
if (!$first_name || (strlen($first_name) > 32)) 
    die('error: first_name');
```

Back in the registration page,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerForm').ajaxForm(function (response) {
        if (response == 'success') {
            alert('Thank you, your registration has been processed.');
            window.location.replace('myURL'); //actual URL in real code
            //TODO redirect to success page
        } else {
            alert('Registration failed, ' + response);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead the page prints

error: first name

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is correct syntax. It'll check for anything that doesn't equal FALSE, which in PHP can be 0 for an int, or NULL, or an empty string etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your form is getting submitted the "normal" / non-ajax way so that would mean that there is a problem with the javascript:

1. jQuery is not loaded;
2. The Form plugin is not loaded;
3. You have an error in your javascript (I don't see any in what you have posted).

Comment: I checked #2 using
if (jQuery-form) echo "<p> Working </p>"; and it did not print so this is my problem. Thank you very much for your help!